# jQuery multiple form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple forms in different page, Is there a way to write a `single function` which would take care of `validation` or should i write code for each form `separately`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $('#fvujq-form1').validate();
    $('#fvujq-form2').validate();
});
```

**Note**: Each form has its own rules.

Update:

```
$("form").each(function () {
        $(this).validate({

            rules: {

                username: {
                    required: true
                },
                password: {
                    required: true
                },
                name: {
                    required: true,                        
                },
                cperson: {
                    required: true,                       
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                return false; //temporarily prevent full submit
            }
        });
    });
```

Now the `username` and `password` of different form and `name` and `person` is of different form in **different page**. Is it right to proceed in this way of having a common form submission.

Comment: if each form has different rules then it is best to use different code

Comment: I wouldn't take this approach. I would simply go through the inputs, determine that type of data we expect and check that it's there (or not there if you have optional fields) leave checking that all the right fields are present to the server-side validation. The reason for this is that it is trivially easy to circumvent client-side JavaScript form validation. (see my answer)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the $("form") selector to validate all elements of type form if that's what you are asking for. I would not recommend that specifically for a page with multiple forms though.

Comment: I am using that, will it work if the rules are different for two forms.

Comment: I would think it would, however if you have multiple forms on one page, it would validate them all at once, I don't know if that is something you would like to have.

Comment: I believe this can get tricky specifically if you have multiple forms on your page, check this JSfiddle for you to test : http://jsfiddle.net/XXm2R/1/

Answer (score 2):

You should test using `$('form').validate();`, if that doesn't work, then use:

```
$('form').each(function(){
    $(this).validate();
});
```

Comment: This approach has worked for me, but I'm finding that I'm falling into the separate validation per form camp.  The rules and methods you may end up adding to make validation work for one form, can negatively influence other forms.  This has been particularly onerous with regard to groups of checkboxes for me.  I'm going to refactor my HTML / JS into separate validation schemes, rules, messages, etc., instead of trying to do it all in a single validation.

Answer (score 1):

If you can give each input element in your form a custom `xx-field-type` attribute eg:

`<input type='text' xx-field-type='email'/>`

You could use:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    validate: function() {
        var input_list = this.find("input");
        for (var i = 0; i < input_list.length; i++) {
            switch(input_list[i].attr("xx-field-type")) {
                case 'username':
                    var value = input_list[i].val();
                    if (value.match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/) != true) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'password':
                    var value = input_list[i].val();
                    if (value.match(/[a-z]+/) != true 
                        || value.match(/[A-Z]+/) != true
                        || value.match(/[0-9]+/) != true) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'email':
                    var value = input_list[i].val();
                    if (value.match(/^[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9]$/) != true) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    continue;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

This would go through each input field of a form, check the value of it's `xx-field-type` attribute and use that to choose the rules that the value must match. Returns false if any fail otherwise returns true.

If you can't add custom attributes you could use classes but it feels hacky to denote form type using an attribute intended for setting display related stuff.

**Untested**

the field types I've used and the regexps are just for the purposes of demonstration.